# $\arctan (x)=2\arctan(1/2)$, what's the value of $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $$\arctan(x)=2\arctan(1/2),$$ then what's the value of $x$?

Answer (score 3):

double angle formula: $$\tan(2\alpha) = \frac{2\tan(\alpha)}{1-\tan^2(\alpha)}$$

$$\arctan(x) = 2\arctan(\frac{1}{2}) \implies x = \tan(2\arctan(\frac{1}{2}))$$

let $$\alpha = \arctan(\frac{1}{2})$$

therefore
$$x = \frac{2\tan(\arctan(\frac{1}{2}))}{1-\tan^2(\arctan(\frac{1}{2}))}$$
$$x = \frac{2\cdot \frac{1}{2}}{1-\Big ( \frac{1}{2}\Big)^2} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{4}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan^{-1}(x) = 2\tan^{-1}\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)$$
Let $\tan^{-1} \big(\frac{1}{2}\big) = a$.
$$\tan^{-1}(x) = 2a$$
$$\tan[(\tan^{-1}(x)] = \tan(2a)$$
$$x = \tan(2a)$$
Recall the double-angle identity for tangent.
$$\tan(2a) = \frac{2\tan(a)}{1-\tan^2(a)}$$
$$x = \frac{2\tan(a)}{1-\tan^2(a)}$$
Now, replace $a$ with $\tan^{-1}\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)$.
$$x = \frac{2\tan(a)}{1-\tan^2(a)}$$
$$x = \frac{2\tan\big[\tan^{-1}\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)\big]}{1-\tan^2\big[\tan^{-1}\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)\big]}$$
Now, just simplify.
$$x = \frac{2\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)}{1-\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^2}$$
$$x = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}}$$
$$\boxed{x = \frac{4}{3}}$$